# standalone cropping my figure in half

Tags: standalone

I'm trying to match the font in the figures for a journal, and to do so I am using the standalone package. The problem I have is that no matter what I do (and I've seen many different posts online), the figure stays the same size and part of the text is cropped from the figure! This is the code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, convert={size=640x}]{standalone}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} % use color
\usepackage{amsmath} % AMS Math Package
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Use the Adobe Times Roman as the default text font together with math symbols from the Sym­bol, Chancery and Com­puter Modern fonts
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\hfsetfillcolor{black!10}
\hfsetbordercolor{black!0}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks, calc, spy, pgfplots.polar}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[notext, nomath]{stix}
\usepackage[safe]{tipa}
\newcommand{\scOmega}{\text{\textscomega}} % small omega
\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}{0.5\linewidth} 
   \input{./bar.pdf_tex}    
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

The input file is a LaTeX file that was produced using inkscape, which includes the real figure plus a lot of text:

```
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{149.64100342bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.30124765)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{bar.pdf}}%
    \put(0.23646628,0.15941548){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{}}}%
    \put(0.12434405,0.14187978){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$E_{\textsc{i}}A$}}}%
    \put(0.43,0.14187978){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$E_{\textsc{ii}}A$}}}%
    \put(0.18809462,0.07146346){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$x_{\Gamma}$}}}%
    \put(0.44530057,0.23115246){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$k$}}}%
    \put(0.69398861,0.19129858){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$P$}}}%
    \put(0.70302227,0.03028893){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$ u \left(L \right) = \frac{ P wL} { E_{\textsc{i}} A}+ \frac{P}{k} + \frac{ P (1 - w)L} { E_{\textsc{ii}} A} $}}}%
    \put(0.30366301,0.02409467){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$L$}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

The result of using the standalone package is:

[image]

Comment: (1) isn't it easier to draw this directly in tikz instead, (2) look up the argument to the picture env, that is most likely the problem, those arguments control the size latex thinks this image has.

Comment: You can wrap the entire picture env or your varwidth env in `\fbox{...} ` to get latex to draw the size it thinks the material has.

Comment: All the text is set in zero-size boxes (`\makebox(0,0)...`), so they're not considered when the bounding box is calculated.

Comment: It worked! I had to change the `\begin{picture}(1.4,0.30124765)%` inside the figure!